# Get content into array using DOM XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, php-curl

I am trying to get the title, info and time into array. However, I am stuck at getting the data. As you can see in my controller, I use getelementbyID to call my first-list, but it shows me the DOMElement Object. Can anyone help? :/

HTML :

```
<div class="col-sm-7 tracking">
    <div class="box">
       <ul id="first-list"> 
        <li>
           <span></span>
                 <div class="title">BKI</div>
                 <div class="info">SHIPMENT DELIVERED</div>
                        <div class="time">
                            <span>01/May/2020</span>
                            <span style="color:grey">9:05PM</span>
                        </div>
        </li>

        <li>
           <span></span>
                  <div class="title">BKI</div>
                  <div class="info">SHIPMENT OUT FOR DELIVERY</div>
                      <div class="time">
                            <span>01/May/2020</span>
                            <span style="color:grey">8:56PM</span>
                        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $DOM->loadHTML($response);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
    $tbody = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('col-sm-7 tracking');

    $query = '//li';

    $entries = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        echo $entry->nodeValue . "<br>";
    }
```

Trying to build an array like:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Text 1
            [Info] => Text 1
            [Time] => Text 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Text 2
            [Info] => Text 2
            [Time] => Text 2
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses XPath to find the relevant parts underneath each `<li>` tag to extract the various pieces of information.  The thing to remember is to use the `<li>` as the start point for the subsequent expressions (pass it as the second parameter to the XPath call).

Some calls where you just need the text I've used `evaluate()` so it saves an extra step to get the text...

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $title = $entries = $xpath->evaluate('string(div[@class="title"])', $entry);
    $info = $entries = $xpath->evaluate('string(div[@class="info"])', $entry);
    $timeParts = $entries = $xpath->query('div[@class="time"]/span', $entry);
    $time = [];
    foreach ( $timeParts as $part ) {
        $time[] = $part->textContent;
    }
    $output[] = [ "title" => $title, "info" => $info, 
        "time" => implode(" ", $time) ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! Especially at the class="time" T_T